# Simple Hibernate Mapping Issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get a simple mapping done but I am having issues.

Basically what I have in Mysql is a User table with just one column that is a `varchar(255)` named Username that is the primary key.

I have one other table called notes which has a primary auto-generating key that is an `int`, a `date` column, `varchar` name and contents columns and a `varchar(255)` called owner which should contain a user's username.

This is tagged as a foreign key referencing Users (Username).

The code to get the session factory is this:

```
 private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Note.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new 
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

This works fine without the line that adds the annotated class 'Note' so it is probably an issue with that class. The error is this:

Could not get constructor for 
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    org.hibernate.MappingException

Full [stacktrace](https://hastebin.com/uvuvuficet.css):

Full classes are available here:

[Note](https://hastebin.com/olekofonun.java)

[User](https://hastebin.com/emomicufac.java)

[Test](https://hastebin.com/xesogomiha.java)

UPDATE: fixed Owner/OwnerName variable misnaming however I now get this error: ERROR:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`notes`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Owner`)
>   REFERENCES `users` (`username`))

[Stacktrace](https://hastebin.com/wokigazoce.coffeescript).

Comment: Share the Note.java code

Comment: @Vigneshwaran https://hastebin.com/olekofonun.java here it is

Comment: The stacktrace is not suffice. Please share full stacktrace that contains "caused by"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the Note class.
For the variable owner, setter method name is not proper.
Instead of

```
public void setOwnerName(String u) { 
this.owner = u; 
}
```

It should be

```
public void setOwner(String u) { 
this.owner = u; 
}
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the first error however I now have this error when attempting to run:
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`notes`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Owner`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`))

Comment: Can you share your hibernate.cfg.xml file?
Have you defined some configuration there?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/foruvaleke.xml here it is. 
Also here is the sql describe on the notes table in case thats relevant: https://hastebin.com/atalixosaz.rb

Comment: okay. I might have found the issue. Try saving user first and then note in your testSave method

Answer (score 1):

you should first save user then save note in your test class.
your code should be like this.

```
    @Test
    public void testSave() {

       Session session = factory.openSession();
       Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
       User user = new User("Joseph");
       Note note = new Note();
       note.setName("Joseph's note");
       note.setContents("blah blah blah");
       note.setOwnerName("Joseph");
       session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(user);
       session.save(note);
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();
       System.out.println(date);
   }
```

but with this code, you just have foreign key in database and you don't have relation in your code.
your note enttiy can be like below code.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
 public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
```

finally your test class can be like :

```
    @Test
    public void testSave() {

       Session session = factory.openSession();
       Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
       User user = new User("Joseph");
       Note note = new Note();
       note.setName("Joseph's note");
       note.setContents("blah blah blah");
       note.setOwner(user);
       session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(user);
       session.save(note);
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();
       System.out.println(date);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very informative. Upvoted but accepted other answer because he solved issue first

Comment: You're Welcome ;)